# Case Switch Statement with Class Object in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection, pattern-matching, type-erasure

I'm trying to use a case switch statement in Scala to check what class/type a Java `Class` object represents. I can't pass the actual object, but I can get the class and I need to perform different logic depending on that class object. For example,

```
def foo(classObj: Class[_]): Any = {
  classObj match {
    case map: Map[String, String] => doMapThings()
    case str: String => doStringThings()
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't really work because the case statement is looking at the type of Class, which is Class, and will never be Map or String. How can I get the type/class that `classObj` represents and match on that instead?

Comment: Can you explain the context of this? Passing a class object and returning `Any` feels  like working against the type system rather than with it. Why can't you pass the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply do the obvious:

```
def foo(c: Class[_]): Unit = {
  if (c == classOf[Map[_, _]]) println("do Map things") 
  else if (c == classOf[String]) println("do string things") 
  else println("do sth. else") }
}
```

You could rewrite it as a `match`-expression using `if`-guards:

```
c match {
  case x if x == classOf[Map[_, _]] => ... 
  ...
}
```

but this doesn't seem any shorter or clearer. Also note: you can't tell a `Map[Int, Double]` and a `Map[String, String]` apart at runtime because of the type erasure.